# Regex getting converted when checked-in to github

Tags: regex, github, gitattributes

I'm having the regex in one of the file as shown below.

```
pattern = "^[^,&*\n\t\r]*"
```

But when i check-in that to github, it's getting converted to invalid characters as shown in the below image.

[image]

I have added the .gitattributes as shown below. Still getting this error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
* text=auto
*.proto text
```

Comment: You probably can fix it by using regex escapes rather than literal chars, `pattern = "^[^,&*\\n\\t\\r]*"`. Or, use hex entities, `pattern = "^[^,&*\\x0A\\x0D\\x09]*"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i tried this as well. when i gave "^[^,&*\\s]*" and check-in the code to github, its removing the one backslash and the resultant code is "^[^,&*\s]*" which is wrong. Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: So, what do you mean it is wrong? Do not try `\s`,  I suggested something else.

Comment: i mean the pattern defined like this - "^[^,&*\\s]*" is going as an input to the regex compiler where it expects to like this - com.google.re2j.Pattern PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION__PATTERN = com.google.re2j.Pattern.compile("^[^,&*\\s]*$"); Since github is removing backslash build is failing,

Comment: Does **`pattern = "^[^,&*\\n\\t\\r]*"`** work? Now, if you are sure you need those backslashes, why don't you double them?

Comment: I will try with pattern = "^[^,&*\\n\\t\\r]*". i dont think doubling is good solution right?

Comment: Why not if it must fix the problem?

Comment: Please write this in the solution - pattern = "^[^,&*\\x0A\\x0D\\x09]*". i can accept this as answer. Thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the hex notation for each of the whitespace chars:

```
pattern = "^[^,&*\\x0A\\x0D\\x09]*"
```

This way, the pattern will be passed as `^[^,&*\x0A\x0D\x09]*` text and `\xNN` regex escapes will be parsed by the regex engine itself, not by the language engine.